# Enter null(date) from DB2 saved as 0002-11-30 (oracle)

Tags: oracle, db2, sql-loader

I have extracted data from DB2 z/os table which data type as below;

TABLE : LIVING IN DB2

```
UPD_DATE TIMESTAMP ,
SEND_FILE CHAR ,
SEND_FILE_DATE TIMESTAMP
```

Here is extracted data in text file.

```
UPD_DATE|SEND_FILE|SEND_FILE_DATE
20080223 035719|Y|
20080223 035736|Y|
20080223 035748|Y|
20080223 035757|Y|
20080223 035719|Y|
20080223 035736|Y|
20080223 035748|Y|
20080223 035757|Y|
20100216 020537|Y|20100217 120000
20100216 020551|Y|20100217 120000
20100216 020615|Y|20100217 120000
20100216 020626|Y|20100217 120000
```

Please note that when select send_file_date in db2 it shows 2010-02-17 00:00:00, however in file 20100217 120000

Here is the target table in Oracle

```
UPD_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) ,
SEND_FILE CHAR(1) ,
SEND_FILE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
```

The issue is if col:send_file_date is null, it is shown as 0002-11-30.

Comment: You need to explain in detail how exactly you are loading your text file and how you view the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause.I extracted the text file by Dbeaver then use sql loader to input data into oracle database. I found that there is ^M at the end of each line. After remove this ^M, I can insert data into oracle table.